# line chart not working using react-d3-components in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linechart, create-react-app

I'm new to react and I'm trying to put react-d3-component in the create-react-app boilerplate.

App.js looks like :

```
import ReactD3 from 'react-d3-components';
import React from 'react';

var LineChart = ReactD3.LineChart;
var Brush = ReactD3.Brush;
var d3 = ReactD3.d3;

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: {label: '', values: [
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 5), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 6), y: 2},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 7), y: 0},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 8), y: 3},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 9), y: 2},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 10), y: 3},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 11), y: 4},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 12), y: 4},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 13), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 14), y: 5},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 15), y: 0},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 16), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 16), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 18), y: 4},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 19), y: 4},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 20), y: 5},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 21), y: 5},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 22), y: 5},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 23), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 24), y: 0},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 25), y: 1},
                {x: new Date(2015, 2, 26), y: 1}
            ]},
            xScale: d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2015, 2, 5), new Date(2015, 2, 26)]).range([0, 400 - 70]),
            xScaleBrush: d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2015, 2, 5), new Date(2015, 2, 26)]).range([0, 400 - 70])
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <LineChart
                    data={this.state.data}
                    width={400}
                    height={400}
                    margin={{top: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 20}}
                    xScale={this.state.xScale}
                    xAxis={{tickValues: this.state.xScale.ticks(d3.time.day, 2), tickFormat: d3.time.format("%m/%d")}}
                />
                <div className="brush" style={{float: 'none'}}>
                    <Brush
                        width={400}
                        height={50}
                        margin={{top: 0, bottom: 30, left: 50, right: 20}}
                        xScale={this.state.xScaleBrush}
                        extent={[new Date(2015, 2, 10), new Date(2015, 2, 12)]}
                        onChange={this._onChange}
                        xAxis={{tickValues: this.state.xScaleBrush.ticks(d3.time.day, 2), tickFormat: d3.time.format("%m/%d")}}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    _onChange: function(extent) {
        this.setState({xScale: d3.time.scale().domain([extent[0], extent[1]]).range([0, 400 - 70])});
    }
});
export default App;
```

index.js looks like :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i have already installed react-d3-components also it's there in package.json ; still I get errors like :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'LineChart' of undefined

Also, where ever there is d3.time.day there it says unresolved function. I also tried importing d3 the other way using :

import * as d3 from 'd3'.

But still I get some different errors.

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong, so that I can set up my initial code to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
import { LineChart, Brush, d3 } from 'react-d3-components';
```

It seems to me like those are named exports rather than a single default export.

Comment: Hoe can I make width for 100% to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be importing d3 properly, which might be causing reactd3 to be imported improperly as well. Try importing d3 like this at the top:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
```

Comment: as given is question; imported d3 like : import * as d3 from 'd3'.

Comment: it definitely seems like the error is coming from the fact that ReactD3 is undefined. Try changing LineChart in the react component to ReactD3.LineChart, and importing ReactD3 inside index.js